# CSS :not() not working

Tags: css

I want to select all elements within a div with the class .test and I do that succesfully like this

```
.test * {}
```

That selects absolutely all children of the .test element, althought don't want to select children with class .nope or any children of .nope, I tried the following but it doesn't work. It actually deselected all children.

```
.test *:not( .nope )

<div class="test">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="nope">
      <div></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the `.nope` is a direct child of `.test`, then you can use `.test>*:not(.nope)` which works - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryfgcfar/)

Comment: Actually its dynamic and will not always be direct children of it.

Comment: @UserDy: That CSS is correctly *selecting* the elements you want. Perhaps the problem is that your are manipulating an attribute inherited by their children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
.test * {color:red;}
.test .nope * {color: initial;}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4tz9qb1x/

Comment: Very nice and simple solution, although will setting "initial" alter the styles of the children? Or does initial apply the style that was previously set within the css?